# monitorInterval is not working in log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, error-logging

I tried to use log4j2 in my application to allow dynamic reconfigure of log levels in the runtime. But I am not able to get monitorInterval work successfully. The Console and file appenders work fine. Here is my log4j2.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="5">
<Appenders>
<Console name="consoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
  <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
</Console>
<File name="fileAppender" fileName="learning.log" append="true">
  <PatternLayout pattern="%t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n"/>
</File>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
<Root level="error">
  <!--  <AppenderRef ref="consoleAppender"/>-->
  <AppenderRef ref="fileAppender"/>
</Root>
</Loggers>  
</Configuration>
```

Please help find the issue.Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you were experiencing this problem while running in Eclipse, please be aware that Eclipse will copy your log4j2.xml file from ${project}/src to ${project}/bin. Log4j will load the log4j2.xml file *in the classpath*, which is ${project}/bin. If you now modify the other config file in your src/ folder, that may not be copied to the bin/ folder until Eclipse detects that a rebuild is required. Perhaps only a change to a .java file triggers a rebuild.

So, modifying the src/log4j2.xml will not "work" because log4j loaded the config from bin/log4j2.xml.

If the config file location is specified there is no possibility of confusion: both yourself and log4j have the same understanding of the config file location.

If this doesn’t solve the issue, try running with system property `-Dlog4j.debug`: that will show internal log4j2 logging on the console, including from what location the configuration is loaded. See also the [FAQ](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#troubleshooting).

Comment: Hi I have my application deployed on Jboss Eap 6.4. I have modified the log4j2.xml file in the directory where the application can see the file during the runtime. However it is still not working. Please advise.

Comment: Try running with system property `-Dlog4j.debug`: that will show internal log4j2 logging on the console, including from what location the configuration is loaded. See also https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#troubleshooting